# Sorting multiple results on the same page using PHP and Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, sorting

My page has two columns. **Column1** for player1, **column2** for player2.
For each column I have a dropdown to choose one of the players.

With some ajax en php codes I return the folowing info of each player. For example:

**Col1**: Tom, Football: 8 points Basketball: 5 points

**Col2**: Jonathan, Football: 4 points Basketball: 9 points

Now I want to let the users sort the results: So I add another dropdown in each column:

**PHP**

```
echo "<select id='filter_class' name=\"filter\"
data-userid=\"".$user_id."\" onchange=\"getFilter(this.value)\">
<option value=\"all\">All</option>
<option value=\"asc\">Asc</option>
<option value=\"desc\">Desc</option> 
</select>";
```

**AJAX**

```
 function getFilter(filter)
{
    var user_id = document.getElementById('filter_class').getAttribute('data-userid');
    console.log(user_id);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://website.com',
        data: {action: filter, user_id: user_id},
        success: function (result) {
            $("#Target").html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see, the dropdown use the **user_id** and the **option value** to sort the results.

this code works only for 1 column, because he keeps (**Ofcourse**) using the first user_id. For example when I try to sort the second results, he sort the results of the first user_id (Normal).

I want that the **SORT DROPDOWN** use the **user_id** of the player is **selected** in the same column.

**IMPORTANT**

I want to use the sort option after showing both results on the page.

Comment: is the html being output inside of a loop?

Comment: @Haider Ali: No. Everytime when someone choose a player, the value is always the user_id.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create your SORT dropdowns with different ids. Let's say you have the id's `id='filter_class1'` and `id='filter_class2'`.

Now you need to pass the id of the calling dropdown to the `getFilter()` function like this.

```
onchange=\"getFilter(this.value, this.id)\"
```

First few lines of your `getFilter()` function should look like this:

```
function getFilter(filter, eleId)
{
    var user_id = document.getElementById(eleId).getAttribute('data-userid');
    console.log(user_id);

...
```

Answer (score 0):

There can only be one element with one id.

You might wanna use the class attribute alongside the data attribute. 
Using jquery's class selector.

Take a look at this example.

```
<select class='filter_class' name="filter"
data-userid="29" >
<option value="all">All</option>
<option value="asc">Asc</option>
<option value="desc">Desc</option> 
</select>

<select class='filter_class' name="filter"
data-userid="30" >
<option value="all">All</option>
<option value="asc">Asc</option>
<option value="desc">Desc</option> 
</select>

<script>
$(".filter_class").change(function(){
    var user_id = $(this).data('userid');
    alert(user_id);
})
</script>
```